# Issue while downloading laravel on windows 10 " [ErrorException] file_get_contents(C:\composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Im trying to install Laravel on my windows 10, when I enter  this command

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

I get this Error:

**Error**

> [ErrorException] file_get_contents(C:\composer): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Run an elevated command prompt.

Right click command prompt > select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I ve tried this solution but still the same problem